# Problemas con el método darLibro()

Tags: java

Estoy empezando en la programación y tengo un problema con el método `darLibro()` que me retorna los atributos de la clase libro; tengo un método `main` donde implemento un menú, una clase llamada `Persona` para el nombre del autor del libro y una clase Fecha donde valido la misma, la clase fecha no se encuentra en el mismo paquete que la clase libro, Persona y menú*(es donde implemento la interacción con el usuario).*

Este es el código de la clase libro:

```
package ejercicio18;

import ejercicio8.Fecha;


public class Libro {

    //Atributos

    private String libro;
    private String isbn;
    private int paginas;
    private String edicion;
    private String editorial;
    private String lugar;

    //Relaciones con las demas clases

    private Fecha fecha;
    private Persona autor;

    //metodos getter and setter

    public String getLibro() {
        return libro;
    }

    public void setLibro(String libro) {
        this.libro = libro;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public int getPaginas() {
        return paginas;
    }

    public void setPaginas(int paginas) {
        this.paginas = paginas;
    }

    public String getEdicion() {
        return edicion;
    }

    public void setEdicion(String edicion) {
        this.edicion = edicion;
    }

    public String getEditorial() {
        return editorial;
    }

    public void setEditorial(String editorial) {
        this.editorial = editorial;
    }

    public String getLugar() {
        return lugar;
    }

    public void setLugar(String lugar) {
        this.lugar = lugar;
    }

    public Fecha getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Fecha fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Persona getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(Persona autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    // metodo Constructor

    public Libro (String libro, String isbn, int paginas, String edicion, String editorial, String lugar )
    {
        this.libro = libro;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.paginas = paginas;
        this.edicion = edicion;
        this.editorial = editorial;
        this.lugar = lugar;
    }

    //metodo dar libro que retorna la informacion del libro

    public String darLibro()
    {
        String miLibro = "Titulo: "+ this.libro+"\n"+this.edicion+"\n"+autor.darNombre()+"\n"+this.isbn+"\n"+this.lugar +"\n"+fecha.corta()+"\n"+this.paginas;
        return miLibro;
    }
}
```

Clase `Persona`

```
package ejercicio18;
public class Persona {

    //Atributos
    private String nombre;

    //metodos

    //Constructor

    public Persona()
    {
        this.nombre = "";
    }

    public Persona(String nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }



    public String darNombre()
    {
        return this.nombre;
    }

}
```

Clase `Fecha` que esta en otro paquete

```
package ejercicio8;

public class Fecha {

    private int dia;
    private int mes;
    private int año;

    public int getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    public int getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    public int getAño() {
        return año;
    }

    public void setAño(int año) {
        this.año = año;
    }

    public Fecha() {
        this.dia = 1;
        this.mes = 1;
        this.año = 1900;
    }

    public Fecha(int dia, int mes, int año) {
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.año = año;
        this.valida();
    }

    public void leer(int dia, int mes, int año) {
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.año = año;
        this.valida();
    }

    public boolean bisiesto() {
        if ((año % 4 == 0) && (año % 100 != 0) || (año % 400 == 0)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int diasMes(int mes) {
        if ((mes == 2) && (this.bisiesto())) {
            return 29;
        }
        if ((mes == 2) && (!this.bisiesto())) {
            return 28;
        }
        if ((mes == 4) || (mes == 6) || (mes == 9) || (mes == 11)) {
            return 30;
        }
        //if ((mes==1)||(mes==3)||(mes==5)||(mes==7)||(mes==8)||(mes==10)||(mes==12))
        return 31;
    }

    private void valida() {
        if ((año < 1900) || (año > 2050)) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes = 1;
            this.año = 1900;
            return;
        } else if ((mes < 1) || (mes > 12)) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes = 1;
            this.año = 1900;
            return;
        } else if ((mes == 2) && (this.bisiesto()) && (dia > 29)) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes = 1;
            this.año = 1900;
            return;
        }
        if ((mes == 2) && (!this.bisiesto()) && (dia > 28)) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes = 1;
            this.año = 1900;
            return;
        }
        if (((mes == 4) || (mes == 6) || (mes == 9) || (mes == 11)) && (dia != 30)) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes = 1;
            this.año = 1900;
            return;
        }
        if (((mes == 1) || (mes == 3) || (mes == 5) || (mes == 7) || (mes == 8) || (mes == 10) || (mes == 12)) && (dia != 31)) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes = 1;
            this.año = 1900;
            return;
        }

    }

    public String corta() {
        String miFecha = this.dia + "-" + this.mes + "-" + this.año;
        return miFecha;
    }

    public void siguiente() {

        if ((dia == 28) && (mes == 2) && (!this.bisiesto())) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes += 1;
            return;
        }
        if ((dia == 29) && (mes == 2) && (this.bisiesto())) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes += 1;

            return;
        }
        if ((dia == 30) && (diasMes(this.mes)==30)) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes += 1;

            return;
        }
        if ((dia == 31) && (mes == 1) || (mes == 3) || (mes == 5) || (mes == 7) || (mes == 8) || (mes == 10)) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes += 1;

            return;
        }
        if ((dia == 31) && (mes == 12)) {
            this.dia = 1;
            this.mes = 1;
            this.año += 1;
            return;
        }
        this.dia += 1; 

    }

    public void anterior() {
        //validar los años bisiestos

        if ((dia == 1) && (mes == 3) && (this.bisiesto())) {
            this.dia = 29;
            this.mes -= 1;
            return;
        }  
        if ((dia == 1) && (mes == 3) && (!this.bisiesto())) {
            this.dia = 28;
            this.mes -= 1;
            return;
        } //validar los meses con 31 dias
        if ((dia == 1) && (mes == 2) || (mes == 4) || (mes == 6) || (mes == 8) || (mes == 9) || (mes == 11)) {
            this.dia = 31;
            this.mes -= 1;
            return;
        }
        if ((dia == 1) && (mes == 1)) {
            this.dia = 31;
            this.mes = 12;
            this.año -= 1; 
            return;
        }
        if ((dia == 1) && (mes == 5) || (mes == 7) || (mes == 10) || (mes == 12)) {
            this.dia = 30;
            this.mes -= 1;
            return;
        }
        this.dia = this.dia - 1;
    }

     public String copia() {
        String micopia = this.dia + "-" + this.mes + "-" + this.año;
        return micopia;
     }

     public boolean igualQue(Fecha fecha2){
         if ((this.dia == (fecha2.getDia())) && (this.mes == (fecha2.getMes())) && (this.año == (fecha2.getAño()))){
             return true;
         } 
        return false;
     }

     public boolean menorQue (Fecha fecha2){
         if (this.año < (fecha2.getAño())){
             return true;
         }
         if ((this.año == fecha2.getAño()) && (this.mes < fecha2.getMes())){
         return true;
         }
         if ((this.año == fecha2.getAño()) && (this.mes == fecha2.getMes()) && (this.dia < fecha2.getDia())){
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

     public boolean mayorQue (Fecha fecha2){
         if (this.año > (fecha2.getAño())){
             return true;
         }
         if ((this.año == fecha2.getAño()) && (this.mes > fecha2.getMes())){
         return true;
         }
         if ((this.año == fecha2.getAño()) && (this.mes == fecha2.getMes()) && (this.dia > fecha2.getDia())){
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

}
```

Clase `Main` donde implemento el menú

```
package ejercicio18;
import ejercicio8.Fecha;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Menu {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        //Atributos
        ArrayList<Libro> libro; 
        Persona p1 = new Persona();
        Fecha f1 = new Fecha();
        int opcion; int numero;
        String titulo; String isbn; int paginas; String edicion; String editorial; String lugar;
        String autor; int dia;int mes; int año;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        libro = new ArrayList ();

        do{

            System.out.print("Ejercicio Biblioteca Municipal\n");
            System.out.println("1. Agregar Libro");
            System.out.println("2. Ver cantidad de Libro");
            System.out.println("3. Numero del Libro (ver Libro en esa posicion)");
            System.out.println("4. Insertar nuevo libro en la posicion deseada");
            System.out.println("5. Eliminar Libro en la posicion indicada ");
            System.out.println("6. Buscar libro por Nombre: ");
            System.out.println("7. Salir ");
            System.out.println("Digite su opcion: ");
            opcion = sc.nextInt();
            switch (opcion){
                case 1:
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Nombre del libro: ");
                    titulo = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("ISBN: ");
                    isbn = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Numero de paginas: ");
                    paginas = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Edicion: ");
                    edicion = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Editorial: ");
                    editorial = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Lugar de expedicion: ");
                    lugar = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Autor: ");
                    autor = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Fecha de expedicion:\nDia: ");
                    dia = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Mes: ");
                    mes = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Año: ");
                    año = sc.nextInt();
                    p1.setNombre(autor);
                    f1.setDia(dia);f1.setMes(mes);f1.setAño(año);
                    Libro  l1= new Libro(titulo, isbn, paginas, edicion, editorial, lugar);
                    libro.add(l1);
                break;    
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Cantidad de libros: "+ libro.size());
                break;
                case 3: 
                    System.out.print("Indique la posicion del libro que desea consultar: ");
                    numero = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Libro: "+libro.get(numero).darLibro());
                break;
                case 4:
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Nuevo libro: \n");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Nombre del libro: ");
                    titulo = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("ISBN: ");
                    isbn = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Numero de paginas: ");
                    paginas = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Edicion: ");
                    edicion = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Editorial: ");
                    editorial = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Lugar de expedicion: ");
                    lugar = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Autor: ");
                    autor = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Fecha de expedicion:\nDia: ");
                    dia = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Mes: ");
                    mes = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Año: ");
                    año = sc.nextInt();
                    p1.setNombre(autor);
                    f1.setDia(dia);f1.setMes(mes);f1.setAño(año);
                    Libro  l2= new Libro(titulo, isbn, paginas, edicion, editorial, lugar);
                    System.out.print("Indique la posicion en la que desea guardar el nuevo libro");
                    numero = sc.nextInt();
                    libro.add(numero, l2);
                break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.print("Indique la posicion en la que desea eliminar el libro");
                    numero = sc.nextInt();
                    libro.remove(numero);
                    System.out.print("LIBRO ELIMINADO");
                break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.print("BUSCAR LIBRO\n");
                    System.out.print("Nombre del libro: ");
                    titulo = sc.nextLine();
                    boolean existe = false;
                    int cont = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < libro.size() && !existe; i++){
                        if(titulo.equals(libro.get(i).getLibro()));
                           existe = true;
                           cont += i;
                    }
                    if (existe == true)
                        System.out.print("El libro es: "+libro.get(cont).darLibro());
                    else if(existe==false)
                        System.out.print("El libro no se encuentra en la base de datos");
                break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.close();
                default:
                    System.out.print("OPCION ERRONEA");

                    }System.out.println();

            }while(opcion !=7);


            }

    }
```

La ejecución me arroja el siguiente error cuando realizo una opción donde se ve involucrado el método `darLibro().`

> BUSCAR LIBRO Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Nombre del libro: at ejercicio18.Libro.darLibro(Libro.java:104) at
>   ejercicio18.Menu.main(Menu.java:121)
>   C:\Users\Adriana\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 40 seconds)

Comment: Has probado debugguear cada clase de forma separada? Te pregunto, porque en tú método `darLibro()` ocupas métodos de otras clases, que si bien las instancias están correctas, quizás los métodos en sí sean los defectuosos. Por cierto, te recomendaría que utilizaras [String format](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) para ahorrarte muchos signos de más (+) y esa pesadilla de concatenación.

Comment: Otra cosa, en tu clase `Menu`, cuando tratas de ingresar un nuevo libro, luego que ingresas el número de páginas de dicho libro hay un `scanner.nextInt()`, pero luego de ese, hay un `scanner.nextLine()`... Es eso a propósito y yo soy el que no lo ve, o puede ser que ahí esté causando algún error?

Comment: ese scanner.nextLine() que vez ahi solo, es para que no me de el salto al  ingreso de datos me expilco, cuando solicito: (edicion: editorial) aparece asi por eso utilizo este metodo para que me deje digitar edicion:______________ y despues editorial:_____________

Comment: @JhonJamesHernandez el error que indicas es al iniciar cuando seleccionas la opción 3?

Comment: @Federico si en la opcion 3 y 6 donde solicito darLibro()

Comment: es decir en tu opinion me aconcejas no usar el metodo darLibro() y realizarlo en el metodo menu, para llamar  metodos de  otras clases solo en esta clase?

Comment: @JhonJamesHernandez eso sería quizá lo más idóneo, así tendrías una clase "Principal" desde la cual mandas parámetros, pero también llamas a métodos de otras clases; claro, tienes que crear instancias y quizás modificar un poco algunos métodos, pero personalmente, encuentro esa solución más eficaz.

Comment: Creo que ya los compañeros te han indicado en respuestas tu error. Aunque no vi que nadie hizo referencia a que nunca creas una nueva instancia de la clase `Persona` para indicar los datos del autor del libro. Eso te dará problemas. Y no entiendo por qué quieres re-inventar la rueda, creando una clase `Fecha` cuando [Java ya tiene una Clase que sirve para manejar las fechas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Tampoco estoy de acuerdo con el consejo de sacar el método `darLibro` de la clase `Libros`. Sería un error, ya que ese método es propio de esa Clase.

Comment: listo es de gran ayuda ya que de ustedes aprendo mucho muchas gracias por todos sus comentarios aplicare todos sus puntos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica en dos puntos importantes, sus constructores están mal construidos , es decir no asigna o `setea` correctamente todos los atributos de su clase `Libro`

```
public Libro (String libro, String isbn, int paginas, 
              String edicion, String editorial, String lugar ) {...}
```

Esos son los datos que asigna directamente desde el main cuando hace

```
new Libro(titulo, isbn, paginas, edicion, editorial, lugar);
```

Pero en su método `darLibro()` , hace uso de `autor.darNombre()` que es una instancia de la clase `Persona` y `fecha.corta()` que es una instancia de la clase `Fecha` las cuales son nulas ya que no se les asigno sus valores.

Entonces la solución vendría por ahí, asignar los valores desde el método main y modificar el constructor de su clase `Libro`

**Libro.java**

```
public Libro (String libro, String isbn, int paginas, String edicion, String editorial, 
             String lugar,Fecha fe ,Persona autor )
{
    this.libro = libro;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.paginas = paginas;
    this.edicion = edicion;
    this.editorial = editorial;
    this.lugar = lugar;
    this.fecha = fe;//seteamos fecha
    this.autor = autor;//seteamos autor
}
```

**Main.java** , en el método para insertar, tendría que modificar de la siguiente forma.

```
case 1:
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Nombre del libro: ");
    titulo = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("ISBN: ");
    isbn = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Numero de paginas: ");
    paginas = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Edicion: ");
    edicion = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Editorial: ");
    editorial = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Lugar de expedicion: ");
    lugar = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Autor: ");
    autor = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Fecha de expedicion:\nDia: ");
    dia = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Mes: ");
    mes = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Año: ");
    año = sc.nextInt();
    // en lugar de asignar con el setter y una nueva instancia en la fecha
    // podría utilizar el constructor de la clase y pasar directamente
    // el día , mes, año , de igual forma para el autor, 
   // utilizar el constructor de la clase Persona
    Libro  l1= new Libro(titulo, isbn, paginas, edicion, editorial,
          lugar,new Fecha(dia, mes, año),new Persona(autor));
    libro.add(l1);
break;
```

Comment: gracias nuevamente aplicare tus concejos :)

Comment: @JhonJamesHernandez genial , un gusto ayudar. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

El método `darLibro()` se usa en la opción 3 de tu programa, pero al iniciar no tienes un libro almacenado, por lo tanto si tratas de llamar el método:

```
libro.get(numero).darLibro()
```

marcara error, ya que no tienes validado verificar la cantidad de libros almacenados, y solo permitir buscar si el numero de libro es menor que la cantidad de libros almacenados, debes validar:

```
...
    case 3: 
                    System.out.print("Indique la posicion del libro que desea consultar:  ");
                    numero = sc.nextInt();

                    if(numero < libro.size()){
                       System.out.print("Libro: "+libro.get(numero).darLibro());
                    }else{
                       System.out.print("NO existen libros!\nSeleccione otra opción");
                    }
                break;
...
```

En cuanto a la opción 6 llamas el método `darLibro()`, el cual internamente trata de llamar el método `darNombre()` de una instancia de la clase `Persona` llamada `autor` que tiene valor nulo:

```
String miLibro = "Titulo: "+ this.libro+"\n"+this.edicion+"\n"+autor.darNombre()+"\n"+this.isbn+"\n"+this.lugar +"\n"+fecha.corta()+"\n"+this.paginas; //* ERROR!
```

El nombre del libro lo puedes obtener del mismo objeto mediante `this.libro`, por lo tanto realiza la modificación a tu método:

```
    public String darLibro()
    {
       // String miLibro = "Titulo: "+ this.libro+"\n"+this.edicion+"\n"+autor.darNombre()+"\n"+this.isbn+"\n"+this.lugar +"\n"+fecha.corta()+"\n"+this.paginas;
        String miLibro = "Titulo: "+ this.libro+"\n"+this.edicion+"\n"+this.libro+"\n"+this.isbn+"\n"+this.lugar +"\n"+fecha.corta()+"\n"+this.paginas;
        return miLibro;
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias @Jorgesys verificare si el numero es menor a la cantidad de libros gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 1):

He visto tu código, en la **clase libro** tienes lo siguiente:

```
 public Libro (String libro, String isbn, int paginas, String edicion, String editorial, String lugar )
{
    this.libro = libro;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.paginas = paginas;
    this.edicion = edicion;
    this.editorial = editorial;
    this.lugar = lugar;
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que son los datos que estas agregando.

En la **clase Menu** tienes lo siguiente:

```
Libro  l1= new Libro(titulo, isbn, paginas, edicion, editorial, lugar);
                libro.add(l1);
```

El error que te marca es porque el metodo `darLibro()` se encuentra vacio, esto es el null de tu error, realmente ese método no realiza la funcion que planteas porque de alguna manera queda vacio, entonces, tendrias que cambiar  a`System.out.print("Libro: "+libro.get(numero).getLibro() +" "+libro.get(numero).getPaginas(),... );`

Hasta Formar tu respuesta

Puedes hacerlo get y set ese metodo.

Comment: `ese método no te sirve para nada` es una afirmación muy vana, según el código dicho método se comporta como un `toString()`,  sirve justamente para evitar eso que plantea en el `main`. acceder atributo por atributo. 3:)

Comment: Creo que me exprese mal, lo que intentaba decir es que expresado de esa forma, no realiza alguna función, sino que de alguna manera queda vacío, corregiré la respuesta.

Comment: es una gran opción compañero gracias :)